# Properties of a Matrix of Frames

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, adjoint-operators, frame-theory

Currently investigating this question :

Let $s = \{s_1, s_2, ..., s_M\}$ be a set of $M \geq N$ vectors in $\mathbb{C}^N$ and let $S$ be a $N \times M$ matrix s.t. $S = [s_1, s_2, ..., s_M]$, what are sufficient conditions on S s.t. $s = \{s_m\}$ is a frame for $\mathbb{C}^N$, what are the frame bounds and what is the frame operator?

My input :

Since $\mathbb{C}^N$ is equipped with the usual inner product, we can state as per frame definition that

$A_s \cdot \left\| x \right\|_{\mathcal{H}}^2 \leq \sum_{n = 1}^M | \langle x, s_n \rangle |^2 \leq B_s \cdot \left\| x \right\|^2$

I can take the inner term and rewrite that to

$\sum_{n = 1}^M | \langle x, s_n \rangle |^2 = \sum_{n = 1}^M \left| \sum_{j = 1}^N x_j \overline{S_{j, n}} \right |^2$

If I am not mistaken, this should be equal to $\left\| \Theta x \right\|_{l^2}^2$ with $\Theta$ being the analysis operator. We know then that $S = \Theta^*$ (which is the synthesis operator) and that $S$ must have rank $M$ s.t. $s = \{s_m\}$ is a frame.

The bounds are then formally given as :

1. $A_s \leq \frac{\left\| \Theta x \right\|_{l^2}^2}{\left\| x \right\|^2}$
2. $B_s \geq \frac{\left\| \Theta x \right\|_{l^2}^2}{\left\| x \right\|^2}$

and i think that I read in this book  [Frames For Undergraduates](https://faculty.sites.iastate.edu/esweber/files/inline-files/book_final.pdf) that $A_s = \lambda_{min}$ and $B_s = \lambda_{max}$ with $\lambda_i$ being eigenvalues of of $SS^*$.

For the frame operator $F = SS^*$ I am really stuck. I know that $F$ should be self-adjoint and positive, so in theory, I should be able to write according to SVD that

$F = U^* \Lambda U$

However, I am not sure. Does anybody mind quickly going through that and suggesting some alternative for $F$ ? Or a more precise statement?

Edit :

F looks as the following and represents a matrix full of outer product terms where the diagonals are note squared norms of the frame elements.

$
\begin{align*}
    F = S \times S^* &= 
    \begin{bmatrix}
     s_{1, 1} & s_{2, 1} & ... & s_{M, 1} \\
     s_{1, 2} & s_{2, 2} & ... & s_{M, 2} \\
     \vdots & \vdots & ... & \vdots \\
     s_{1, N} & s_{2, N} & ... & s_{M, N} 
    \end{bmatrix} \cdot 
    \begin{bmatrix}
     \overline{s_{1, 1}} & \overline{s_{2, 1}} & ... & \overline{s_{M, 1}} \\
     \overline{s_{1, 2}} & \overline{s_{2, 2}} & ... & \overline{s_{M, 2}} \\
     \vdots & \vdots & ... & \vdots \\
     \overline{s_{1, N}} & \overline{s_{2, N}} & ... & \overline{s_{M, N}} 
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    &= 
    \begin{bmatrix}
     \sum_{j = 1}^M s_{j, 1} \overline{s_{j, 1}} & \sum_{j = 1}^M s_{j, 1} \overline{s_{j, 2}} & ... & \sum_{j = 1}^M s_{j, 1} \overline{s_{j, N}} \\
     \sum_{j = 1}^M s_{j, 2} \overline{s_{j, 1}} & \sum_{j = 1}^M s_{j, 2} \overline{s_{j, 2}} & ... & \sum_{j = 1}^M s_{j, 2} \overline{s_{j, N}} \\
     \vdots & \vdots & ... & \vdots \\
     \sum_{j = 1}^M s_{j, N} \overline{s_{j, 1}} & \sum_{j = 1}^M s_{j, N} \overline{s_{j, 2}} & ... & \sum_{j = 1}^M s_{j, N} \overline{s_{j, N}}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
$